# Merging to child branch causes deletion of new child branch content in TFVC, how to fix?

Tags: version-control, tfs

Where I work, we have a branching strategy that basically says there is a topmost `main` (call it main, trunk, whatever) which is always stable, then a project group, then a project, both with their respective `main` branches (taken from one level "up", closer to the topmost main). At the project level, further branching for specific features may or may not be done, depending on the complexity of the work involved. (No need to create a feature branch to fix a few identified user interface text typos, for example.) In general, this works well. We also source control the database layer as a part of the larger source code tree, so there is a `database` structure under each source root directory.

In the `database` subtree, there is a `patch` directory with (in most branches) a single child directory. That directory is named from `vCurrent` (for example, if vCurrent is 2.3 SP1 HF0, then the patch directory will be named `2.3 SP1 HF0`) and contains patches that will upgrade the database schema (possibly with data transformation) from vCurrent to vFeature. `vFeature`, here, is the version in which the branch in question goes production; that might be `vNext`, `vFuture` or (in extreme cases) `vNever` if development doesn't pan out for some reason. Feature branches generally don't have a target release version, but they may have a target release date.

Hence, the structure looks something like the following:

```
main
    database
        patch
            2.3 SP1 HF0 <--- indicating that "main" is at version 2.3 SP1 HF0
projectgroup1
    main
        database
            patch
                2.3 SP1 HF0
    project1
        main
            database
                patch
                    2.3 SP1 HF0
        feature1
            database
                patch
                    2.3 SP1 HF0
```

Now, imagine that a critical bug is discovered in production and necessites an immediate fix, with the result of pushing `main` to version 2.3 SP1 HF1. Or management decides to do a release (perhaps of only one feature branch) to satisfy market requirements, giving us 2.4 SP0 HF0. Or whatever. Patches "from" 2.3 SP1 HF0 that were not applied in the release may or may not still be applicable, but most importantly, that must be decided on a case-by-case basis by the developer responsible for each branch. **Thus, a new patch directory with the new current version number is created, and the old one is deleted because it is no longer relevant** (it's still available from source control by checking "display deleted items", as well as in the release drop branch, so getting to the content of a specific release is not a problem). When merging this changeset to their respective feature branches, each developer is expected to look over their sets of database patches and update them as necessary to comply with any schema changes coming from upstream.

Normally, this is not a big problem, as the changes to the patch structure are made at the topmost `main` (which, again, is stable) and trickle downwards.

However, **if a second** (to the released) **feature branch exists** with its own set of database patches, TFVC will trickle down the delete operation on main's 2.3 SP1 HF0 patch directory seemingly without regard to the fact that that second feature branch has added content to the deleted directory, **and delete those new patches along with `patch\2.3 SP1 HF0`**. This is clearly undesirable.

In my mind, the situation in feature branch 2 is a conflict: one side of the merge says delete, the other says new files that have never been merged to the source of the merge. In that situation, TFVC should step aside, present this as a conflict, and ask the programmer who is doing the merge what to do. Note that there may even be files under that directory with same names but different content (this is by design). Instead, it just pulls the rug out from under your feet by deleting the directory and all its contents outright.

Currently, we deal with this mostly by doing "undo pending changes" on the deletion, then moving the new patches and deleting the old directory manually. This clearly feels suboptimal, as well as being extremely risky (all it would take is one developer not checking in their full set of pending changes before merging the "minor" change from upstream, while they have fresh database patches locally, and you have lost work and much frustration).

Working within the confines of TFS and TFVC (so please don't say "use Git in DVCS mode" or the likes), **is there a way to actually have this presented as a conflict?** Or are we out of luck and just have to settle for handling this situation manually? It doesn't happen terribly often, but with the large number of branches, there is clearly the risk of a mistake slipping through.

Comment: FAQ says tools discussions are for SO,  voted to move it for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use both git and tfs at the same time. Look up git-tfs. Get the best of both worlds. The biggest gain is that you won't have to deal with base less merges anymore. This is the core of your issue. When merging it is very beneficial to base the conflicts in the common base to both sides of the conflict.

There is no "dvcs mode" in git, BTW.

We do aggressive branch per feature. This is or workflow:

https://plus.google.com/109096274754593704906/posts/R4qkeyRadLR

Technology aside, I hope it helps you out with your branch issues. At least in tfs, if you manually mark the beginning of some dev effort, you can compare the patches from both sides.

Comment: "The biggest gain is that you won't have to deal with base less merges anymore. This is the core of your issue." Could you please clarify that part? At the time of the merge, the merge target branch code is not ready for integration. Also, this is not just for me, but for the whole team, and unless I can present concrete facts of advantage over our current branch strategy in our usage, I think an entirely new branch strategy would be kind of a hard sell.